# React Functional setState vs object difference

Tags: reactjs, setstate

sDoing a React course I faced with a strange situation deleting object from state. The course author used non-functional state update but I tried to make it functional and got an error. It would be great if you explain the principal difference in those two approaches.
To begin with state looks so:

```
{
  items: {item11 : {_item1Props_}, item2: {item2Pros}},
  order: {_some_suff_in_the_cart}
}
```

The following code performed for deleting item2:

```
deleteItem = key => {
  const items= {...this.state.items, [key]: null};
  this.setState({items});
}
```

All the components which use state updated with no errors (cart, view and so on).
Trying to make setState functional I got error in render methods of other components with the following code:

```
deleteItem = key => {
  this.setState(prevState =>(
    {
     items: 
      {...prevState.items, [key]: null}
    }
  ));
}
```

Even more the following code failed as well:

```
deleteItem = key => {
  const items= {...this.state.items, [key]: null};
  this.setState(prevState => ({items}));
}
```

So, there must be a principal difference in those methods?
Thank you in advance!

**UPD** components code:
There are two components using state:

```
TypeError: _this$props$details is null
```

Comes from the component which renders item:

```
class Item extends Component {
  render() {
    const {name, desc, price, status, image} = this.props.details;
    const isAvailable = status === "available";
    return (
      <li className="menu-item">
        <img src={image} alt={name}/>
        <h3 className="item-name">
          {name}
          <span className="price">{formatPrice(price)}</span>
        </h3>
        <p>{desc}</p>
        <button 
          disabled={!isAvailable}
          onClick={()=>{this.props.addToOrder(this.props.index)}}
        >
          {isAvailable ? "Add To Cart" : "Sold Out"}
        </button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

and

```
TypeError: this.props.item is null
```

from the component which is used to edit items:

```
class EditItemForm extends Component {
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const updatedItem = {
      ...this.props.item,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    this.props.updateItem(this.props.index, updatedItem);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="item-edit">
        <input 
          name="name" 
          type="text" 
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.props.item.name}
        />
        <input 
          name="price" 
          type="text" 
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.props.item.price}
        />
        <select 
          name="status" 
          value={this.props.item.status}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <option value="available">Available</option>
          <option value="unavailable">Sold Out</option>
        </select>
        <textarea 
          name="desc" 
          type="text" 
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.props.item.desc}
        />
        <input 
          name="image" 
          type="text"  
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.props.item.image}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPD2:**
I logged the render() methods of mentioned components I found out that object version removes the property at all, so the null is not passed to the components meanwhile the functional preserves the null value when state is passed to the components.

Comment: That second snippet should work. What error are you getting from that one exactly?

Comment: @Tholle I have updated the description

Comment: are multiple deletes happening in rapid succession, or are there other setState calls?

Comment: @lecstor no other updates are happening, just this one

Comment: the only observation I can make then is that with the non-function setState version the child components are not seeing the `null` value, which they see with the function version and they obviously don't handle it. I can't seem to replicate this difference though.

Comment: @lecstor I logged the render() methods of components and found out that functional version preserves null in the props while object version does not pass it at all

Comment: that is odd. Are you able to reproduce that in codesandbox? I had a go but didn't see it, must be missing something. https://codesandbox.io/s/zom5x8114

Comment: Hi All! 
Thanks for your time. I forgot to mention that I used firebase sync.
Digging a bit deeper I found out that the issue could be in Firebase ('re-base' package) which I used for state sync. Having an object  with null value passed Firebase deleted the related property and then all the other components got the state which synced with Firebase. In case of function components got null before sunc with firebase. So, all in all, it is not a React-related question. 
Once again, thanks for your time!